# What restrictions apply to flying RC and UAV planes in India at very low altitudes?

Tags: airspace, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, dgca-india-regulations

We are working on a UAV and will soon get to the testing phase. We intend to fly at a maximum altitude of 300-400 meters. I wanted to know as to what restrictions apply to the airspace in India (specifically Delhi) with respect to flying UAVs as well as the altitudes from which they apply?

We will also be testing autonomous capabilities. Do we need to get any licenses for this?

Comment: I'm not sure we have anyone familiar with India's airspace rules here (yet) - but either way you'd probably want to contact someone from [the Directorate General of Civil Aviation](http://www.dgca.nic.in) which is your regional regulatory body. As much as you might get good advice here, you really want to be sure you're operating within the limits of appropriate regulation, and because UAVs are still "new territory" in most countries it's often helpful to talk to the regulatory agency directly.

Comment: Also, if you find your own answers via the DGCA, please come back here and answer your own question. It will help other people down the road, and is good for the site.

Answer (score 7):

The Director General of Civil Aviation has published [this public notice](http://dgca.nic.in/public_notice/PN_UAS.pdf):

> GOVERNMENT OF INDIA OFFICE OF THE DIRECTOR GENERAL OF CIVIL AVIATION
>   OPPOSITE SAFDARJUNG AIRPORT, NEW DELHI – 110 003
>
> PUBLIC NOTICE   File No. 05-13/2014-AED Dated: 7th October, 2014
>
> Subject: Use of Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV)/ Unmanned Aircraft
>   Systems   (UAS) for Civil Applications
>
> Of late, lots of interests are being shown for civil use (both
>   commercial and recreational) of UAS in the country. International
>   Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) is yet to publish Standards And
>   Recommended Practices (SARPs), as far as certification and operation
>   of civil use of UAS is concerned.
>
> UAS has potential for large number of civil applications. However, its
>   use besides being a safety issue, also poses security threat. The
>   Airspace over cities in India has high density of manned aircraft
>   traffic. Due to lack of regulation, operating procedures/ standards
>   and uncertainty of the technology, UAS poses threat for air collisions
>   and accidents.
>
> The civil operation of UAS will require approval from the Air
>   Navigation Service provider, defence, Ministry of Home Affairs, and
>   other concerned security agencies, besides the DGCA. DGCA is in the
>   process of formulating the regulations (and globally harmonize those)
>   for certification & operation for use of UAS in the Indian Civil
>   Airspace. Till such regulations are issued, no non government agency,
>   organization, or an individual will launch a UAS in Indian Civil
>   Airspace for any purpose whatsoever. The above is for strict
>   compliance.
>
> Director General of Civil Aviation

Answer (score 6):

Since no-one has answered this yet, I'll give it a crack.

According to the [Unmanned Systems Association of India](http://www.usai.in/regulations.html), UAVs are required to submit a specific request to the Directorate General of Civil Aviation to allow them to fly UAVs in a specific area.

For RC aircraft, you must make sure that they use one of the following frequencies ([source](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2009-07-31/india/28208731_1_frequency-planes-customs)):

- 27004 KHz
- 27116 KHz
- 27148 KHz
- 27156 KHz
- 27228 KHz

I'm not so sure about what makes an aircraft in the RC category, as opposed to an UAV though -- if someone could fill me in on that, that'd be great.